# accessing data from a pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble accessing data from an extra column in a pivot table.

I have two models (which are part of a larger application for managing grades in a k-12 school) - Grado and Subject.  Grado refers to the grade, i.e first grade, second grade, etc.  I want the administrator to be able to associate subjects to a grade level in a given year.

The mysql pivot table grado_subject contains:

- id_grado_subject
- year_grado_subject      //year - column I want to access
- grados_id_grados        //foreign key id of grado
- subjects_id_subjects    //foreign key id of subject
- created_at
- updated_at

The Grado model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Grado extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

        use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;


          protected $table = 'grados';
          protected $primaryKey = "id_grados"; 
          protected $fillable = array('name_grados');


           public static $rules = array(
            );

                  public function subject()
              {
                  return       $this->belongsToMany('Subject','grado_subject','grados_id_grados','subjects_id_subjects')
              ->withPivot('year_grado_subject')
              ->withTimestamps();
              }

           public function groups()
           {
               return $this->hasMany('Group','id_grados','grados_id_grados');
           }

    }
```

The Subject Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Subject extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
            use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

            protected $table = 'subjects';
            protected $primaryKey = "id_subjects"; 


               protected $fillable = array('engSpanExtra_subjects', 'name_subjects','IntGrade_subjects');


            public static $rules = array(
               'name_subjects' => 'required',   
               'engSpanExtra_subjects' => 'required',
               'IntGrade_subjects'=> 'required'

           );
        public function grado()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Grado','grado_subject','subjects_id_subjects','grados_id_grados')
               ->withPivot('year_grado_subject')
               ->withTimestamps();
        }

         public function teacher()
         {
              return $this->belongsToMany('Teacher','subject_teacher','subjects_id_subjects','teachers_id_teachers');

         }

}
```

In the GradoController:

```
class GradoController extends \BaseController {


    public function index()
    {

        $grados = Grado::find(1);
        $years = $grados->pivot->year_grado_subject;// line I get error on
        return $years;
        $grados->toarray();


        return View::make('grados.index',compact('grados', 'years'));
}
```

When I try to retrieve all the years associated with a grade_subject I get the error:  Trying to get property of a non-object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `pivot` attribute is generated by the `belongsToMany` relationship, therefore it exists on the objects loaded by that relationship (subjects), not the primary object (grado).

For example:

```
// primary object is grado
$grado = Grado::find(1);

// loop through related subjects
foreach($grado->subject as $subject) {
    // pivot attribute exists on related subject
    echo $subject->pivot->year_grado_subject;
}
```

Or, if you were going the inverse way:

```
// primary object is subject
$subject = Subject::find(1);

// loop through related grados
foreach($subject->grado as $grado) {
    // pivot attribute exists on related grado
    echo $grado->pivot->year_grado_subject;
}
```

Comment: Yes,thank you!  It makes perfect sense now, I was wondering, in the case there are more than one belongsToMany relationships in a model, how Laravel would know which one to pull up.

Comment: @Bapi Yes, it is. It's right in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Answer (score 0):

> public function subject()
>                 {
>                     return       $this>belongsToMany('Subject','grado_subject','grados_id_grados','subjects_id_subjects')
>                 ->withPivot('year_grado_subject')
>                 ->withTimestamps();
>                 }

You have some syntax errors I'm seeing in the above. First you have *$this>belongsToMany* which should be **$this->belongsToMany**

Another thing you  might check is *$this->belongsToMany('Subject', ...)* You aren't including your Student model in a use clause therefore you have to use a fully qualified reference and it should be $this-**>belongsToMany('\Student', ...)**.

You have the same syntax errors in your Grado model. Check these first and see if your error is solved.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The syntax error resulted from fiddling with the code when I pasted it in; I checked my file and it was correct (sorry). I'm not sure about including the Student model as it is related via Group...?  If I do $grados->name_grados (which is a column in my grados table) it works just fine.  I just can't seem to access the pivot table data.  BTW I can attach grados and subjects just fine.